# Path created for background image is wrong in the template using webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-5, webpack-loader

I am trying to build my template files using webpack 5. The issue is the path of the background image that is being generated is "basic-project/dist/stylesheet/img/webpack-bg.png", instead it should be "basic-project/dist/img/webpack-bg.png". Attached is the webpack.config.js file screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I can easily help you if you share a reproducible repo rather than just images?

Comment: Github Link:
https://github.com/sachindra149/webpack5

Branch: dev-branch

Comment: Is your issue using `index.hbs` template and can't resolve the image src inside that?

Comment: no the issue is I have defined styling in css file, src/stylesheet/index.scss. but when i generate the template using npm run start, the path generated is wrong.
I hv updated the template file

Comment: @tmhao2005, were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I dropped you what I found as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232324/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-sachindra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have set up everything right. As you mentioned, the actual issue is from the `output.publicPath` value. Basically, the right one should be set as `/` in most cases:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    // ...
    publicPath: '/',
  },
}
```